# How to multiply params from different models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on an app and need to calculate two different params from different models. I have a `Place` model and a `User` model. The `Place` model has a `cost:float` param and the `User` model has an `adult:integer` param. When I try to multiply them using:

```
<%= place.cost * current_user.adult %>
```

I get

```
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

None of these params are `Nil` because when I run:

```
<%= place.cost %><%= current_user.adult %>
```

I get values for both.

Granted, I'm sure this would be best done as a method in the model instead of in the view but I could figure out how to make that work either.

Why wouldn't this `*` operation work if they both give me values?

Comment: Is this possible that `<%= place.cost * current_user.adult %>` is part of loop? Maybe there is one `place` which has no `cost` set?

Comment: That's it! Wow, I didn't even think of that. Yea, I did have a 'place' with no cost. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. (I won't tell you have long I spent trying to figure this out...)

Comment: Yeah, I know. This happens to all of us sometimes - one of *those* days :). Created an answer with explanation for your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the code:

```
<%= place.cost * current_user.adult %>
```

is a part of loop, and in the collection of `Place`s that you are iterating through, there is one `place` that has no `cost` set.

Answer (score -1):

Nil has not *place* or *current_user*

Nil has cost or adult
But when you try to render it you have no error

Try this

```
<%= place.cost.inspect %><%= current_user.adult.inspect %>
```

And You will see that one of them has nil.